Sci-fi movie that starts with a man digging his way out of a crashed spacecraft and promptly being torn in half
I broke my leg as a kid and my parents dropped me off at a movie house that showed 3 movies back to back. My dad pulled me out of the 3rd movie and I never got to finish it.
It started with a space crew breaking through the atmosphere of a new planet and crash landing with the escape hatch facing the ground. The crew started digging their way out and as soon as first person breached ground on the other side you heard a terrible animalistic noise with screams. The crew desperately tried retracting their mate and as they pulled him back, he head, torso and arms were ripped clean off up to his chest.
That’s when my dad collected me. Been looking for that film ever since. Circa 1984 -1986.

I suggest the 1985 post-nuclear apocalypse movie Def-Con 4.
The story follows the crew of a space station, in earth orbit and not a new planet, following a nuclear war that leaves them stranded in space. Weeks pass, then the station malfunctions, forcing the crew's emergency return to earth. The capsule crashes with the hatch buried under sand. The crew digs themselves out. The first man screams, there are savage noises, then the crewman's arm dropped back into the hatch. He'd been eaten by radiation-crazed survivors.

